# CentOS 6.8 dropping all connections

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, routing, linux-networking

I have a CentOS 6.8 (Final) server (on Production). How can I allow the incoming connections to eth0 interface from a different private subnet? Currently, it is accessible on the same network (10.0.6.x). Below is my IPTABLES, but currently it is not working as expected.

```
 -P INPUT DROP
 -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 -P OUTPUT DROP
 -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 192.168.6.104/32 -i bond0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 192.168.6.1/32 -i bond0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -i bond0 -j DROP 
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -m comment --comment "ftp" -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "ssh" -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.10.200.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.23.101.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.0.6.0/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A INPUT -s 10.10.100.0/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.6.104/32 -o bond0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.6.1/32 -o bond0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -o bond0 -j DROP 
 -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state NEW -m owner --uid-owner root -m comment --comment "root" -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -s 10.0.6.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
 -A OUTPUT -s 10.10.100.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Can you please help?

Regards,

Comment: Show IP routes rules. What are routers used for each IP network destination?

Comment: Hi Again,

I tried to flush the iptables, but after that, every connection on this server got disconnected. Before I flush it, here are things that I did:

1. iptables -save > iptable.rule

I tried to restore it using iptables-restore > iptable.rule, but still failing. Anything I missed?

Regards,

Comment: Right now, I got disconnected on the server. Please see my last update. Is there anything else that I need to do to restore the connection?

Comment: Connect keyboard and monitor. You have `INPUT DROP` by default. Restarting `iptables` service (or stopping it) saves current rules.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy How can i restart the IPTABLES? What will happen if I'm going to reboot the server? Will the connection to the server go back?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy, heres the result of ip route

ip route show
192.168.6.0/24 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.6.26 
10.0.6.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.6.116 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev bond0  scope link  metric 1006

Comment: Please, edit your question instead writing in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved the issue. I just added a gateway on my interface eth0 and restarted the network service.

Thanks all!